# How can I make a shared jenkins job can be called by different build flow without a queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a shared job , which is used in so many other build flow. When I trigger both the build flow together one will wait for the other to complete .

In  Detail:
Let "Shared Job" be the common job
Let Build Flow1 and Build Flow2 are the build flows.
Build Flow1 is defined like this
Build (Shared Job,param1,param2)
and 
Build Flow2 is defined with some other parameters
Build (Shared Job,param3,param4)

If I trigger both on same one will start the Shared job . The other will be in queue.

I don't want to wait till that time . How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you have to do:

1. In the configuration for 'shared job' enable 'Execute concurrent builds if necessary'
2. Make sure 'Shared Job' is not restricted to a particular slave, or if it is, then make sure the slave has two or more executors.